# Excel how to format spesific cell for number which is formatted incorrectly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a data which is like this:

- 1,537,753
- 2,224,874
- 32,210,587
- 41,210,55
- 52,307,597

I want to format them like this:

- 1.537,753
- 2.224,874
- 32.210,587
- 41.210,55
- 52.307,597

How can i format my values as i said? I need to change first "," to "."

Second "," should stay same.

All helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the turkish version.

```
=SOLDAN(METNEÇEVİR(A1,"#,##0 "),BUL(",",METNEÇEVİR(A1,"#,##0 "))-1) & "." & PARÇAAL(METNEÇEVİR(A1,"#,##0 "),BUL(",",METNEÇEVİR(A1,"#,##0 "))+1,9999)
```

if it doesn't work, then use this one, I replaced **","** with **";"**

```
=SOLDAN(METNEÇEVİR(A1;"#,##0 ");BUL(",";METNEÇEVİR(A1;"#,##0 "))-1) & "." & PARÇAAL(METNEÇEVİR(A1;"#,##0 ");BUL(",";METNEÇEVİR(A1;"#,##0 "))+1;9999)
```

tell me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"#,##0 "),FIND(",",TEXT(A1,"#,##0 "))-1) & "." & MID(TEXT(A1,"#,##0 "),FIND(",",TEXT(A1,"#,##0 "))+1,9999)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. it doesn't work for me. I'm using Excel 2013 Turkish version.